# How do I override CSS custom properties in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to dynamically set the max-height of an element based on the number of children it has.

In my component, I am setting a custom property using:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--children-count', Children.count(props.children));
```

and in my css, I use it like this:

```
&.active {
        .buttonGroup {
            max-height: calc(var(--children-count) * 30px);
        }
    }
```

This works fine if I am only using it once. However, once I start loading multiple instances of the component with different number children, the --children-count gets overwritten and all the preceding components styles get changed.

How do I go around this?

Comment: You have multiple components competing for them same `element`. Why? Do you want the sum of the number of children of all elements?

Comment: Right, that seems to be the problem. I wanted the sum of the children purely because transitions only work with max-height, and if you put a higher value that there is, the animation takes longer than it should

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most probably because you change the value of the `--children-count` CSS variable on the top `documentElement`, therefore affecting ALL your components in the document.

If you want 1 value per Component  then simply apply it on an Element of said Component, see e.g. [How to apply CSS variable on dynamic CSS class in dynamic component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182419/how-to-apply-css-variable-on-dynamic-css-class-in-dynamic-component/75188520#75188520)

If you use `styled-components`, you can also use [style adaptation based on props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) (instead of CSS variables).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sync common data between multiple components, *pull state upwards!* In this case, into a context (unless if you want to manage it with props).

Here's a codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lalande-wjpdgb

The key parts of it are the Context Provider which will handle the shared state

```
function ChildCounterContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ count, setCount }), [count])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handle changes to number of children here
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--children-count', count);
  }, [count]);

  return <ChildCounterContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </ChildCounterContext.Provider>
}
```

...and the context consumer, which will write to it.

```
const useChildCounter = () => useContext(ChildCounterContext);
function MyComponentWithChildren({ children }) {
  const childrenCount = React.Children.count(children);
  const childCounter = useChildCounter();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add when enters
    childCounter.setCount(n => n+childrenCount);
    // Deduct when exits
    return () => childCounter.setCount(n => n-childrenCount);
  }, [childrenCount, childCounter]);

  return <p>I have {childrenCount} children out of {childCounter.count}</p>
}
```

The effects will make sure the counts is always in sync.